# La (très) étrange façon de parler du « commandeur » de Murakami

Tags: ancien-français, style-de-rédaction

Je suis en train d’écouter l’audiolivre « Le meurtre du commandeur », par Haruki Murakami. L’un des personnages de ce roman, si on peut l’appeler « personnage », est une idée dotée de la capacité de s’incarner de temps en temps, en choisissant la forme qu’elle prendra plus ou moins à son gré. À ce stade du récit, la forme choisie est celle d’un personnage d’un tableau (« le meurtre du commandeur ») représentant une scène de l’ancien Japon, et plus précisément celle du commandeur lui-même. L’idée, ou plutôt son incarnation, se présente donc vêtue à la façon d’une époque très lointaine. En même temps, en tant qu’idée, on peut considérer soit qu’elle existe depuis toujours, soit qu’elle existe en dehors du temps – et puis il y a d’autres éléments de l’histoire qui laissent penser qu’elle a peut-être habité, autrefois, l’esprit d’un bonze qui se serait enfermé dans une fosse pour devenir « Bouddha à même le corps. »

Je me demande si les repères linguistiques de ce personnage seraient propres à l’idée elle-même, ou bien empruntés, pour ainsi dire, du commandeur (dont elle emprunte aussi le nom)... ou encore du bonze.

Dès sa toute première apparition, le commandeur n’hésite « point » à introduire dans son discours des « ô que né-ni ! », des « oui-da ! », ou encore des « dam’oui ». Jusque-là j’avais pris ces tournures pour « le français d’autrefois » même si, plus généralement, sa façon de parler reste pour le moins étrange - mais voilà maintenant qu’il dit :

« Longtemps ? Point du tout ! [...] une idée, ça s’en va et ça revient, de par le monde entier, tantôt par ci, tantôt par là, et ça réapparaît tous les cent ans, parfois même tous les mille ans, oui da ! Un jour ou deux, c’est carrément tout à fait que quick ! »

Or, « quick » just can’t be old French. Je me demande donc quelle impression la façon dont le commandeur s’exprime ici pourrait donner à un lecteur de langue maternelle française. Des éclaircissements sur les « ô que né-ni ... » seront tout aussi bienvenus, da m’oui !

Comment: As-tu vu la forme écrite du texte ? Parce que je  soupçonne  des erreurs dans la transcription de l'audio à l’écrit. [Que nenni](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nenni) et voir oui-da employé dans un exemple sur cette page.  [Dam oui](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dam)(subst. fém. et interj). [Que couic](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/couic), (un jour ou deux c'est carrément rien/peu). Et ça ne relèverait pas de l'ancien français, mais d'expression vieillies employées probablement pour créer une atmosphère (je n'ai pas lu le livre).

Comment: Non, je l’avais pas vu (en fait, j’avais pris pour évident le fait que les termes en guillemets, qui semblaient appartenir à une époque passée, ne m’était pas familiers, et qu’il y aurait donc d’éventuelles erreurs à cet égard - merci en tout cas de m’avoir déniché les bonnes orthographes).

Comment: En gros je déduis de toutes ces réponses (très intressantes d’ailleurs) que le traducteur à cherché un effet « moyen-âge » qui correspond au personnage du tableau, mais que ce n’est pas tout à fait réussi. En fait le livre 3 n’a pas encore paru en version française et il se peut donc que je passe bientôt à l’anglais – dans ce cas on verra comment un autre traducteur s’y est pris.

Answer (score 5):

Après avoir trouvé [le texte écrit](https://books.google.fr/books?id=En1oDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT345&lpg=PT345&dq=%22une%20id%C3%A9e,%20%C3%A7a%20s%E2%80%99en%20va%20et%20%C3%A7a%20revient,%20de%20par%20le%20monde%20entier,%20tant%C3%B4t%20par%20ci,%20tant%C3%B4t%20par%20l%C3%A0%22&source=bl&ots=-smTR7HK82&sig=ACfU3U3w-xu4o-PJmgmFJ8GLxdHiIWa-Dw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbvrLStILjAhUF6OAKHVjeDbUQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22une%20id%C3%A9e%2C%20%C3%A7a%20s%E2%80%99en%20va%20et%20%C3%A7a%20revient%2C%20de%20par%20le%20monde%20entier%2C%20tant%C3%B4t%20par%20ci%2C%20tant%C3%B4t%20par%20l%C3%A0%22&f=false) j'ai eu la confirmation que tu avais fait des erreurs de transcription.

> Longtemps ? Point du tout ! répondit abruptement le commandeur, une idée, ça s’en va et ça revient, de par le monde entier, tantôt par-ci, tantôt par-là, et ça réapparaît tous les cent ans, parfois même tous les mille ans, **oui-da**. Un jour ou deux, c’est carrément tout à fait que **couic**.

Définition du « que couic » [dans le TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/couic) :

> Si peu que ce soit; rien.

La phrase est claire : « Un jour ou deux c'est carrément pas beaucoup/peu. »

**[Que nenni](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nenni)** renforcé par **oui-da** indique qu'on s'oppose à ce qui vient d'être dit.

Et ce n'est pas <strike>da m’oui</strike> mais « dame oui », (qu'on pourrait abréger en « dam » mais apparemment [le traducteur du livre n'a pas abrégé](https://books.google.fr/books?id=En1oDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=le%20meurtre%20du%20commandeur&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih0dTEwILjAhUbiVwKHQxzDOIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=dame&f=false)). C'est une interjection marquant ici l'assentiment du locuteur. ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dam))

Rien de tout ça n'est du vieux français mais tout simplement des expressions vieillies probablement employées pour créer l'atmosphère, mais n'ayant pas lu le livre je ne m'avancerai pas plus.

Answer (score 0):

[nenni](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nenni) est un adverbe vieilli qui peut être utilisé pour répondre « non » à une interrogation.

La forme « que nenni »  signifie la même chose mais renforcée.

Pour « que quick », [voir la réponse de Teleporting goat](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37194/635).

Par ailleurs j'écrirais plutôt « Dame oui »

Comment: Sympa le vote négatif ! On peut savoir pourquoi ?

Answer (score -1):

Je pense que tu as confondu "*que quick*" avec "*[que pouic](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que_pouic)*", une expression qui veut dire *rien du tout*, *que dalle*.

C'est un mot d'argot qui je pense n'est pas tout jeune, et plus très utilisé de nos jours, donc ça me paraît plutôt cohérent.

Comment: Ce serait plutôt « couic » et pas « pouic ».

Comment: @Laure: Les deux existent dans le TLFi et signifient la même chose.

Comment: @Laure  je ne connaissais pas "que couic" mais si elle existe c'est sûrement celle-là qui est utilisé dans le livre audio

Comment: @Toto Là n'est pas le problème,  on peut supposer que celui qui a posé la question a bien entendu [kwɪk] et pas [pwɪk]

Comment: J'en déduis que les deux sont assez rares. Il m'était pas venu à l'ésprit qu'il pourrait y avoir un mot français dont la prononciation correspond parfaitement a celle de "quick". Je n'ai donc pas pensé à vérifier ça dans un dico.

Comment: @Minty Rare, certes mais on peut l'employer encore de nos jours pour créer un effet. Il m'arrive d'employer l'expression « je n'y entrave que couic ».

Answer (score -1):

Je vais commencer par la fin qui me semble facile à expédier, et m'attarder sur cette expression apparemment bizarre, « ô que né-ni ».

« Né-ni » fait partie de la vieille langue mais ne s'écrit pas de cette façon là : « nenni » est l'orthographe correcte et c'est un mot qui signifiait « non » et que l'on n'emploie plus, sauf, nous dit le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nenni), par plaisanterie; en vérité on trouvais la forme renforcée « nenni da » où « da » n'a rien à voir avec le russe. « Da » est une interjection qui provient du Moyen Âge et qui sert de renforcement (voir étymologie dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/da), composée des impératif de dire et d'aller (*diva*), s'est ensuite altérée en « dea » puis « da »). Je crois que si des utilisateurs se servent toujours de la forme « nenni » c'est que la rime mignarde les inspire; c'est donc une mignardise.

Il n'y a pas beaucoup à dire à propos de « m'oui » si ce n'est que c'est une interjection introduite dans le langage très récemment et quelle est l'expression d'une affirmation très atténuée (voir [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moui)).

Je ne connais pas l'usage de « quick », n'en trouve aucune trace sur le Web.

Comment: Il s'agit bien de [« **Ô** que nenni »](https://books.google.fr/books?id=En1oDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=le+meurtre+du+commandeur&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih0dTEwILjAhUbiVwKHQxzDOIQ6AEIKDAA#v=snippet&q=%22%C3%94%20que%20nenni%22&f=false).

Comment: @Laure Oui, c'est ce que j'ai assumé ; je ne mets pas l'exactitude de l'orthographe en doute mais seulement  le choix de mot. Il me semble qu'il ne s'agit pas d'une invocation et à l'entrée « nenni » du TLFi on trouve cet exemple : « Oh! que nenni, il n'est pas mort, dit le vieux moine, je le vois qui grouille ». « Ô » serait donc correct en temps que synonyme de « oh » qui sert à exprimer emphatiquement un sentiment dans le syntagme qui suit ?

Comment: Les deux me semblent possible mais il s'agit probablement d'un choix voulu de la part du traducteur. Pour bien comprendre le choix il faudrait lire le livre....

Comment: @Laure Je vois, je vais m'en remettre au TLFi, que je n'avais pas jugé bon de consulter tellement je pensais qu'il ne pouvait pas exister de synonymie, et conclure que parfois on peut écrire « ô » à la place de « oh » et de « ho ».